# Device Rotation with wrong camera overlay dimension

Tags: java, android, angularjs, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am fairly new to coding and app development(almost a month) so please bear with me. I am working on an app that uses a Barcode scanning plugin (customized as per needs).

In the app's main view (first window) I have a block, which on click triggers the Barcode plugin's scan(). This opens a scanner of the exact dimensions as the block of the main view. But if I rotate the device, the Barcode scanner view's dimensions goes haywire.

Is there a way I can adjust/change the x,y,w,h values of the Barcode scanner view so to align it with my app's block in the main view?

Upon clicking the Scan block on my app's main view, this scanner is opened as an overlay with custom buttons:

[image]

Upon rotating the device and clicking the scan block (green block on app's main view), this is how it looks:

[image]

Angular code passing the dimensions for the green scan block on app's main view:

```
.directive('barcodeScanner', function ($localStorage, _, $window) {
function link(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.scanning = false;
    scope.paused = false;
    //Barcode-Scanning Green Window
    var width = $window.innerWidth;
    var height = width * 3/4;
    if(width > 450){
        width = 400;
        height = 300;
    }
    scope.dimensionStyle = {
        width: width+"px",
        height: height+"px",
        "margin-left" : "auto",
        "margin-right" : "auto"
    }
    scope.$on('stop-scanner', function () {
        scope.paused=false;
        stopScanner();
    });
    scope.$on('start-scanner', function () {
        scope.paused=true;
        startScanner();
    });

    var mH = $window.innerHeight,
        mW = $window.innerWidth;
    var startBtn = element[0].querySelector('.barcode-start-btn');
    function startScanner(){
        var rect = startBtn.getBoundingClientRect();
        var options = {
            wPer : rect.width/mW,
            hPer : rect.height/mH,
            yPer : rect.top/mH,
            xPer : rect.left/mW
        }
        scope.scanning = true;
        cordova.plugins.barcodescanner.scan(function(result) {
                    scope.$emit('barcode-scanned',result);
              },
              options
        );
    }
```

My barcodescanner.java of the plugin that is triggered to open the scanner:

```
   @Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    this.requestArgs = args;

    if (action.equals(SCAN)) {
        // create fragment
        if(!hasPermisssion()) {
            requestPermissions(0);
        } else {
            scan(args);
        }
    } else if(action.equals(STOP)) {
        stop(args);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public void scan(final JSONArray args) {
    final CordovaPlugin that = this;

    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            int maxHeight = webView.getView().getHeight();
            int maxWidth = webView.getView().getWidth();
            double xPer = 0/360;
            double yPer = 82/568;
            double hPer = 270/568;
            double wPer = 360/360;
            // add config as intent extras
            if (args.length() > 0) {

                JSONObject obj;
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        obj = args.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(obj.has(X_PER)){
                            xPer = obj.getDouble(X_PER);
                        }
                        if(obj.has(Y_PER)){
                            yPer = obj.getDouble(Y_PER);
                        }
                        if(obj.has(H_PER)){
                            hPer = obj.getDouble(H_PER);
                        }
                        if(obj.has(W_PER)){
                            wPer = obj.getDouble(W_PER);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("CordovaLog", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble("x", maxWidth*xPer);
            bundle.putDouble("y", maxHeight*yPer);
            bundle.putDouble("w", maxWidth*wPer);
            bundle.putDouble("h", maxHeight*hPer);
            openCameraPopup(bundle);
        }
    });
}
```

My fragment class that implements ZxingScannerView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle state) {
    if(state == null){
        state = this.getArguments();
    }
    if(state != null) {
        x = state.getDouble("x");
        y = state.getDouble("y");
        w = state.getDouble("w");
        h = state.getDouble("h");
    }
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity()){
        @Override
        public void setupCameraPreview(CameraWrapper cameraWrapper) {
            super.setupCameraPreview(cameraWrapper);

            buttonStop = new Button(getActivity());
            buttonStop.setText("STOP");

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            this.addView(buttonStop);
            buttonStop.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mScannerView.stopCamera();
                    mScannerView.removeAllViews();
                }
            });
        }
 };
    mScannerView.setZ(10);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
    mScannerView.setFlash(false);
    mScannerView.setX((float) x);
    mScannerView.setY((float) y);
    mScannerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)w, (int)h));

    return mScannerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to lock your position using screen orientation landscape. So it will change position everytime you rotate your mobile.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But if I'm locking the position the app is always opening in landscape mode, even on rotation and that I don't want. I want the scanner overlay's dimensions to be exact for both landscape and portrait modes.